# Matrix transpose in Java (Storing matrix in ArrayList)

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that transposes a given matrix

```
sample input:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 8 0 2

sample output:
1 5 9
2 6 8
3 7 0
4 8 2
```

**My Question is how do i store the input in a multidimensional ArrayList like this:**
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,8,0,2]]

Comment: Do you want a nested list `List<List<Integer>>` or an array like `int[][]`?

Comment: Either one is fine as long as i can reference it like a matrix

Answer (score 1):

You can store the input in the required multi-dimensional List like below:

```
List<List<Integer>>list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4), Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8), Arrays.asList(9, 8, 0, 2));
```

And then you can apply your transpose logic and store the output in a new List of List.

If you are taking input from the console you can do like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
int n = 3;
while (n-- > 0) {
    List<Integer> collect = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.add(collect);
}
```

Please also note here that this is Java 8 syntax.

Comment: the input is coming from the user, i can't manually store the matrix. How can i store it in a way that works for whatever input the user throws?

Comment: the approach still works the same. also, you should have provided all necessary details and the code in your question to avoid this back and forth.

Comment: @Scoopy_Xavier Edited the post assuming you know the number of lines that are there in the input console.

Comment: br is BufferedReader, input taken from console